# Alternative to tf$audio$audio_spectrogram for Tensorflow version 2.0 in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, audio, spectrogram

I'm working through [this example](https://www.kaggle.com/thegrigorian/freesound-code-with-r/data) and it looks like tf$audio$audio_spectrogram is no longer available for Tensorflow 2.0. Is there an equivalent function I could use? I'm looking through the TF directory under [signal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal) and not seeing a 'spectrogram' function. I tried using tf$compat$v1$audio$audio_spectrogram but that didn't work. I'm new to Python and Tf and using TF in R. Thank you

Comment: How about going with STFT?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski how would I substitute that instead of this part of the code? 

spectrogram <- tf$audio$audio_spectrogram(
                        wav$audio, 
                        window_size = window_size, 
                        stride = stride,
                        magnitude_squared = TRUE
                  )

Comment: Update: so I used tf$signal$stft in a different example but will see if theres a way to directly sub this in for audio_spectrogram. @lukasz_tracewski